# In the Data Explorer, can you get the change in the number of views for a single question?

Tags: support, data-explorer, views

I am trying to find out the monthly change in views for a single question in Data Explorer.

I was able to get the current number of views, but could not figure out how to get the past number of views.

Is it possible to get the number of past views with Data Explorer?
And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: TL;DR: it's not possible

Comment: Note, however, that *votes* can be tracked this way, since the time cast is stored for every vote. For example, here's a graph of the [running sum of votes over time for the Syntax Highlighting FAQ post](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1440752/votes-on-post-over-time?PostId=184108#graph).